Setting up KOMA-Script
I'd like to write a simple cover letter, using org-mode. Several
examples I have come across draw on KOMA-Script (e.g.: on
Rida Ayed's webpage).
Running the sample script from Rida Ayed's page throws a few errors,
including "Unknown LaTeX Class 'default-koma-letter'". This suggests
to me that KOMA-Script isn't on my system or at least it isn't
activated. It is stated here
(tutorial) that it's
a prerequisite and may need to be downloaded. Being relatively new to
Emacs and Linux, could someone kindly tell which exact steps I'd need
to take in either Emacs or the terminal (Linux Mint) to download and
set up KOMA-Script so that I can draw on its functionality for
writing letters, particularly any steps needed before I can start following the configuration steps outlined at the above tutorial on org mode and KOMA-Script?

This question has nothing to do with Emacs: it's mostly TeX packages that you'll have to install using Mint's package manager. What you have to install depends on what you have installed already. It also depends on what packages Mint provides. I would redirect this question to a Mint forum.

Thanks a lot for your pointer, NickD. This is very helpful. Believe it or not, but identifying what the actual underlying issue is likely to be is not trivial for those new to the area (Emacs?, TeX?, Linux?). I have reposted my question, as suggested by you, it can now be found here. Many thanks!

That's OK. Asking a question is fine. ls Mint an Ubuntu derivative? If so, a more appropriate forum (in the sense that it would be more likely to deliver answers) might be the Ask Ubuntu forum. If you don't get useful replies on Unix SE, you might try on Ask Ubuntu (but you should not post to multiple places indiscriminately: think about the best place  before asking. It's very annoying to have partial answers spread between two sites). And BTW, you should close the question on this site (as a couple of us have voted to do already).

Thank you, NickD, much appreciated. I am a bit pressed for time these days and don't have time to follow-up on some of the suggestions (yet!). I agree, it's best to keep things compact and avoid spreading the discussion over multiple sites, but then even professionals (e.g. researchers) often cannot fully predict the way things turn out, despite their best intentions to plan everything, when they ask a (research) question ... I haven't found the answer yet, but am happy for the discussion to be closed here for it to continue in a place where it's more pertinent.

So, if your goal is to write something with org-mode and export it through LaTeX Koma letter, you don't have to install anything on Emacs, since ox-koma-letter.el (which handles that) should be part of Emacs already.
However, LaTeX and Koma should be installed on your GNU Linux.
The standard way to install LaTeX on GNU Linux is through Tex Live. So once the Tex Live distribution is installed on your system you can add or remove packages such as koma-script.
There are various ways to install Tex Live on your system, I will mention 3, going from the most common to the less common (personnaly I use the 3d).

Install Tex Live through Mint package manager
Install Tex Live manually (see https://tug.org/texlive/acquire-netinstall.html and https://tug.org/texlive/quickinstall.html)
Install TinyTex (see https://yihui.org/tinytex/)


Thank you so much for your explanation. As suggested by NickD (comment above), I reposted my question here. In a nutshell: TeX Live seems to be installed. Nonetheless, it looks like KOMA-Script cannot be used when exporting with org-mode.

Maybe the koma-script package isn't installed. You can check that with tlmgr (see https://www.tug.org/texlive/tlmgr.html).

Thank you! Following the advice from here, I ran tlmgr info koma-script to check for the package. This gave the following output, suggesting the issue might be a bit more complex and might have to do with the TeX Live installation:
(see /usr/share/doc/texlive-base/README.tlmgr-on-Debian.md)
TLPDB: Cannot determine type of tlpdb from /home/tiberius/texmf!
tlmgr: user mode not initialized, please read the documentation!```

You can try tlmgr install koma-script. If tlmgr is conflicting with Tex Live apt packages, maybe be you should remove it and install Tex Live manually (2.) or through tiny (3) tex instead.

At the very least, you should check if there is a Koma packave available to be installed by the Mint package manager, The TeX Live installation might install enough for "normal" tasks but not the Koma packages. My Fedora 40 shows  six texlive-koma-... packages: I have installed just one texlive-koma-script and AFAIK that's enough to use koma classes with Org mode. But this is a Mint-and-TeX discussion that should be taking place somewhere else, not on Emacs SE.
